# Is MP3 good for cats?

Tags: compression, mp3

As you know, MP3 format is built using some hacks based on things that our ear can't hear. For example human hearing aid can not hear for a milliseconds after short and loud sound. Mp3 compressing uses that and removes that sound bite after 'kicks'.

Is cat hearing aid working the same way? Or cats can hear every compression hack? My cat doesn't care about Strauss at all, is that an MP3 problem?

Comment: This is an interesting question. I'm not sure that Stackoverflow is the best fit for it though. There's a whole bunch of different Q&A sites under the StackExchange banner: https://stackexchange.com/sites  Maybe Sound Design would be a better fit? https://sound.stackexchange.com

Comment: @WhiteHotLoveTiger thanks! You are right, sound.stackexchange.com is better platform for this question. I'll move this topic later because of "You can only post once every 40 minutes."

Comment: "My cat doesn't care about Strauss at all"  I imagine that's because cats don't care about anything.  :-)

Comment: Some Googling says cats can hear up to 64 kHz which is well above even the best human hearing.  Lower bitrate MP3 rolls off around 15 kHz.  Also, 48 kHz is a typical sample rate which physically can't represent frequencies higher than 24 kHz.  If you want to represent the range of cat hearing, look for 192 kHz recordings.

Comment: @Brad thanks a lot! I I'm starting to see how it works. Will make some tests :-)